# Implementing streams with elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, sicp

I'm reading section 3.5 of the [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) book, and I'm trying to implement
streams using Elisp. The book implements streams using the Scheme language as follows:

The core structure of a stream is a pair whose `car` is the current value of the sequence and its `cdr` is the promise of evaluating the next item, which is achieved with the following construction:

```
(define (cons-stream a b) (cons a (delay b)))
```

Where `(delay b)` is equivalent to `(lambda () b)`.

When the `cdr` of this pair is evaluated, it forces the evaluation of the delayed element of the stream so we can get the next element and the implementation is as follows:

```
(define (stream-cdr stream) (force (cdr stream)))
```

Where `(force delayed-object)` is just the execution of `(delayed-object)`.

With this construction we can now easily build recursive procedures with streams transparently as if they were regular lists like in map:

```
(define (stream-map proc stream)
    (if (stream-null? stream)
        the-empty-stream
      (cons-stream (proc (stream-car s))
                   (stream-map p (stream-cdr s)))))
```

I'm trying to write a similar stream implementation using Elisp, but I haven't found a way to implement `delay` so that it allows me to write recursive procedures in a similar fashion as with Scheme, currently my workaround is to put the delay as a lambda expression inside the recursive procedure like this:

```
(defun stream-map (proc stream)
  (lexical-let ((p proc)
                (s stream))
    (if (stream-null? stream)
        the-empty-stream
      (cons-stream (funcall p (stream-car s))
                   (lambda ()
                     (stream-map p (stream-cdr s)))))))
```

Which obviously doesn't look as nice as the Scheme implementation.

These are my Elisp version of the core functions for creating streams:

```
(defun cons-stream (a b) (cons a b))
(defun stream-cdr (stream) (sicp-force (cdr stream)))
(defun sicp-force (exp) (funcall exp))
```

How can I do to write the `delay` and the other stream functions so I don't have to put the `lambda` inside the recursive procedure?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but wouldn't a macro do the job? ``(defmacro delay (&rest body) `(lambda () ,@body))``

Comment: @Gerstmann that's excactly the construction I was looking for. Much appreciated! I'll put the details in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Gerstmann's suggestion I was able to write the construction I was looking for. The new implementation now looks like:

```
(setq the-empty-stream nil)
(defun stream-null? (s) (eq s the-empty-stream))
(defun my/sicp-delay (exp) `(lambda () ,exp))
(defun my/sicp-force (exp) (funcall exp))

(defmacro my/cons-stream (a b) (list 'cons a (my/sicp-delay b)))
(defun my/stream-car (stream) (car stream))
(defun my/stream-cdr (stream) (my/sicp-force (cdr stream)))
```

Now I can write procedures that look just as clean as the Scheme implementation:

```
(defun my/stream-enumerate-interval (low high)
  (lexical-let ((l low)
                (h high))
    (if (> l h)
        the-empty-stream
      (my/cons-stream low
                      (my/stream-enumerate-interval (1+ l) h)))))

; this returns 12
(my/stream-car (my/stream-cdr (my/stream-cdr (my/stream-enumerate-interval 10 20))))
```